# Accumulate values over years in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, daxstudio

My table has a column that calculates the cumulative total year-to-date (YTD). The column is `Balance BRL`. It works ok using the DAX function `DATESYTD`.

[image: The example table]

The column `Balance BRL` is perfectly achieved using the DAX below:

```
Balance BRL = 
CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[realized_application],
    DATESYTD('Calendar'[Date])
)
+
CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[realized_investiments],
    DATESYTD('Calendar'[Date])
)
+
CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[realized_balance],
    DATESYTD ('Calendar'[Date])
 )
+
CALCULATE (
    [Forecast_R],
    DATESYTD ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
)
```

I was asked to continue to accumulate the values over 2023. That is not compatible with the formula `DATESYTD`.

I read this article from daxpatterns.com: [Link Cumulative Total](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/)

I tried to implement it. the result is **-R$ 148.017.749,0527** which is indeed the final balance. But it seems the date does not take effect to properly calculate it by month.

My current measure is the one below. I am fixing the date period until the end of January in 2023 just to test:

```
Balance BRL = 
    var period_begin = DATE(2022,1,1)
    var period_end = DATE(2023,1,31)

return

CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[realized_application],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
)
+
CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[realized_investiments],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
)
+
CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[realized_balance],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
 )
+
CALCULATE (
    [Forecast_R],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
)
```

How to solve this cumulative total that continues to calculate from 2022 until 2023?

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: Here you are: [Link to the PBIX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqQjmeJSKOtIbXHM1OgobRVWlvGVU8no/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want (New Column):

[image]

```
New = 

var period_end = MAX('Calendar'[Date])

return

CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[__auto_application_actutal],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
)
+
CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[__investment_actual],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
)
+
CALCULATE (
    'Fact_balance_cash'[__balance_actual],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
 )
+
CALCULATE (
    [__Forecast_R],
    'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like-

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM('Fact_balance_cash'[realized_application]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[Date]>=period_begin
            && 'Calendar'[Date]<=period_end
    )
    
)
```

There is also a function like DATESBETWEEN you can check.

Comment: It is resulting in -148 milions BRL. Whitch is the result I extpect, but it is repeating all rows like the previou measure I did. [Here is the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7CC2z4KP53tURhfmCkEtHhrP6CvvwMj/view?usp=sharing). [Here is the link to the PBIX - Measure __Total actual test 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11lU47SoMloBP_7jOayDJsXMuW_iWUSHQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR startDate = 
    CALCULATE(
       MIN(Calendar[Date])
      ,AllSELECTED(Calendar)
    )
VAR endDate = MAX(Calendar[Date])

RETURN
    CALCULATE(
           [realized_application] 
         + [realized_investiments] 
         + [realized_balance] 
         + [Forecast_R]
         ,'Calendar'[Date]>=startDate  && 'Calendar'[Date]<=endDate 
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the result is not the one expected. [Here is the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mYXyBJo5cJwQmO79rJfnjiBc300oluoq/view?usp=sharing). [Here is the link to the PBIX - Measure __Total actual test 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqQjmeJSKOtIbXHM1OgobRVWlvGVU8no/view?usp=share_link). The result was supposed to be - 148,46 Millions BRL by the end of January/23

Comment: can you add 2 measures with start and end dates ?

Comment: `MAX(Calendar[Date])` - fist measure to matrix

Comment: `CALCULATE(
       MIN(Calendar[Date])
      ,AllSELECTED(Calendar) )` - second measure to matrix

Comment: then test each measure first `[realized_application]` with the same code just remove other 3, then only with `[realized_investiments]` and so on

Comment: Just to check what is wrong period start end dates or measures results.

Comment: Add measure codes as well

Comment: I'm going to my vacation, so I will not be able to reach the result. Try all steps and you will find the source of the problem. It will help you to find a solution. I think, that my measure is ok. The problem can come from data types, links, measures, filtering etc. So, if you find my answer usefull then you can mark the answer or upvote. I'll be back to SO only in the end of Jan. So, good lack and Happy new year!!!